# Semaphore synchronized wait() and notify()

Tags: java, multithreading, semaphore

I have codes below: this is to get knowledge of semaphore. The codes is Thread A first is waiting since b.wait() (making calling thread sleep), then get notified, Why the code has synchronized here? If no, it gives IllegalMontiorXXXXXXXXX exception.

```
public class ThreadA {
   public static void main(String[] args){
     ThreadB b = new ThreadB();
     b.start();

     synchronized(b){
        try{
            System.out.println("Waiting for b to complete...");
            b.wait();
        }catch(InterruptedException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("Total is: " + b.total);
    }
  }
}



class ThreadB extends Thread{
    int total;
    @Override
    public void run(){
        synchronized(this){
            for(int i=0; i<100 ; i++){
                total += i;
            }
            notify();
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: The answer is that the synchronization let the current thread owns the semaphore. notify() documentation explains that.

Comment: Did you read the documentation for `wait()` and `notify()`?

Comment: By the way, synchronising and waiting on a thread object is a bad idea in general. As is calling `notify()` when you could call `notifyAll()`. There are very few cases where `notify()` is justifiable, and it's better to be safe.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks, the synchronization is to let the thread owner of the semaphore as documentation said.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should only use final objects as monitors. It will save you some nasty bugs.

If your monitor is not made final there is always the chance that it will be set to
reference a new object and in such case code that appears to be synchronized will in fact run
in parallel.  Read [here](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1142811?tstart=0) for more.

Here's how it's done:

**A. Consumer:**

```
static final Object monitor = new Object(); //<---------------
static volatile boolean completed = false;


public class ThreadA {
   public static void main(String[] args){
     ThreadB b = new ThreadB();
     b.start();

     synchronized(monitor) {
          while (!completed) { 
               monitor.wait();
          }
     }

     // when here: producer had completed <-----------------
  }
}
```

**B. Producer:**

```
class ThreadB extends Thread{
    int total;
    @Override
    public void run(){
        for(int i=0; i<100 ; i++) { //<------------ no need to synchronize 
             total += i;
        }

        completed = true; <--------- mark producer as completed

        synchronized(monitor) {
            monitor.notify(); 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Might as well use a [Semaphore](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html) or, in this case, a [CountDownLatch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html). Looking at the [source code for Semaphore](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.java), wait and notify barely scratch the surface.

Using a CountDownLatch makes code easier to read:

```
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;

public class WaitOnCount {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    ThreadB b = new ThreadB(latch);
    b.start();
    try {
        latch.await();
        System.out.println("Total is: " + b.total);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

static class ThreadB extends Thread {

    final CountDownLatch latch;
    int total;

    ThreadB(CountDownLatch latch) {
        super();
        this.latch = latch;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            total += i;
        }
        latch.countDown();
    }
}
}
```